# Eclipse enforce strict java code formatting

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting

What is the best way to ensure that Java code follows a strict set of formatting guidelines. It needs to be configurable so that we can enforce our own guidelines (which are mostly based on Suns original guidelines document).

Im sick of having classes that even in different methods have different formatting depending on the developer who altered that particular method.

When I say strict, I mean, absolutely everything is formatted to a standard.

Comment: The best place to enforce this is in your source control system, so it might be worth stating which one you're using so that you can get matching tools there and in your IDE.

Answer (score 5):

In Eclipse, you can set up your own set of guidelines. Go to Window/Preferences and search for "format", and you'll find **Code Formatter** somewhere in the menu tree. To apply formatting to a file, just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in the editor.

Then you can share the code formatting profile with the entire team, and everybody will be able to format the code the exact same way.

Comment: Wow, I haven't looked at this for a while, the formatter seems quite comprehensive. I wonder if it is possible to apply this formatting to all files in a project at once.

Comment: you can choose to automatically format on save. See Java/Save Action in preferences.

Answer (score 3):

Some source code management systems can be configured to run a command-line formatter on all code being checked in.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to rely on Eclipse alone, you can configure it in the preferences under `Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings` to catch basic style problems and you can configure the formatter to format the code to your specification.

From style perspective, Eclipse options are quite limited so it is better to use external tools like [Checkstye](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net) and [Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net) which can be configured as part of your build process and also work well with Eclipse.

Comment: Well if Eclipse's styling options are quite limited then I don't know how you'd describe Visual Studio's ;) If you mean catching misformated code - I'd think just autoformatting at checkin or save would be easier than another tool.